# Ckeditor not showing my code block when edit code block

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x, fckeditor

Ckeditor is not showing my code block when I edit it.
I show it with the screenshots below.

myconfig file:

```
config.toolbar = 'Full';
config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog';
config.extraPlugins = 'codemirror';
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
config.autoParagraph = false;
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'pre[*]; code[*]';
config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
```

Adding a post:

[image: i add post]

Editing a post:

[image: i edit post]

Source code for text:

[image: source code for text]